# How can I find out why my Rails controller is returning a 500 error code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In testing, a call to `session.get root_path` is returning a 500 error code, i.e. `assert session.response.success?` is failing.

This used to be fine, so clearly I have broken something, but I’m having trouble narrowing down the cause for the following reasons:

- No exception is being thrown.
- The value of `session.response.body` is correct (i.e. it contains the correctly-rendered HTML I was expecting from the `render template: ...` call in the controller.

In other words, nothing appears to have actually gone wrong, but still there is a 500 HTTP response.

Note: I am setting `status = :success` (or some other value) earlier in the controller action, which is then passed to render as `status: status`. This is because I am detecting possible unauthorized access based on some stuff in the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I’ve been unobservant. The method for testing is called `#success?`, but the response code symbol is called `:ok`.

To be fair, the other Rails test methods / response code symbols tend to map directly.

**Clarification:**

So based on Max’s comment, the point here is that `#success?` returns true for any of the 200-family ‘happy’ HTTP codes. It is an umbrella term though, and so cannot be passed to `render`.

I have updated the relevant code to something more like:

```
status = :ok  # This was :success
if redirecting_from_access_denied?
  status = :unauthorized
end
```

Comment: `#success?` allows for more than "200 OK", mainly the other 20x "happy responses".